# Javaのコンパイル時にエラーが出る

Tags: java

Max/mspという作曲用のプログラミング環境で、javaのクラスを使おうとしたところ、
下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

[image: エラー]

JDKのバージョンが古いのかな、と思ってJDK 8 Update 66をダウンロードしてコンパイルし直しましたが、それでもコンソールに上の画像と同じものが表示されます。
どうしたらいいのでしょうか・・・・・・

--追記--
開発環境
OS:Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite
JAVAのバージョン(ターミナルでjava -versionと打ったら出てきたもの):
　java version "1.8.0_66"
　Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
　Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
Max/mspのバージョン:7.0.6

Comment: 利用しているOSや開発環境のバージョン等の情報が明示してあると、より回答が得やすくなるかと思います。

Comment: コンパイルした時のJDKのバージョンと実行する時のJREのバージョンが異なるとこのエラーになりますね。1.7に統一するのが吉かも。

Comment: リンクしている他のjarとかのバージョンは大丈夫ですか？混ぜるとうまくいかないかも。

Comment: @kosh  ご指摘ありがとうございます！追記いたしました。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi max.jarというファイルとリンクさせていたので、それとのバージョンが違ったためにエラーが起こっていたようです。まさにおっしゃる通りでした！

Comment: おお、良かったです。僕もscalaのバージョンを上げたら既存のjarとリンクできなくて、このエラーになったことがあります。

Comment: そうなんですね！このエラーが出たらjarとのリンク等を気にするようにします。勉強になりました^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

特定の製品固有の問題であれば、その製品のサポートフォーラム(等)を覗いてみると問題が解決しやすいかと思います。

今回の場合であれば
https://cycling74.com/forums/forum/java/
ですね。

エラーメッセージで検索してみると、Mac OSXでは
https://cycling74.com/wiki/index.php?title=Category:Max_And_Java
https://cycling74.com/wiki/index.php?title=Java_on_OS_X_10.9_(and_later)

> Max (at least until version 7.0.6) will not work with Oracle Java. To use Java and the [mxj] object in Max you need to (re-) install Java for OS X. There is no problem having Java for OS X installed alongside with Oracle Java. Java applications other then Max will use Oracle Java, Max the other one.
>
> Luckily Apple still offers the old package for downloading [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572).

ということのようなので、使用されているOSがOSXなのであれば、Apple製のJava1.6を使用する必要がありそうです。
つまり原因は(想定とは逆で)、Javaのバージョンが新しいから駄目、というわけです。

Comment: サポートフォーラムというものがあること自体知らなかったです・・・。サイトが全部英語なのでガンスルーしていました。。
ご指摘通り、Java1.6を使うようにしたら無事成功しました。助かりました、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 3):

[How to fix: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10382929/4499880) によると、エラーメッセージ `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` は「JDK 8 をサポートしていません」という意味だそうです。

ひとつ前のバージョン JDK 7 を利用するか、`javac -target 1.7 HelloWorld.java` のようにVMのバージョンを直接指定してコンパイルしてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 2点問題があります。(1)JDK8のjavacを使用する場合`-target 1.7`だけではコンパイル時エラーになりますので`-target 1.7 -source 1.7`のように`-source`オプションで1.7(以前)を明示的に指定する必要があります。(2)Java8対応していないということは質問者の環境はOSXではないかと思われますが、その場合Java7も対応していません。やるなら`-target 1.6 -source 1.6`でしょう(ただしOSX上でOracle Javaはサポートしていないとオフィシャルでは言っているようです)。

Comment: javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 HelloWorld.javaで試したところ、"警告: [options] ブートストラップ・クラスパスが-source 1.6と一緒に設定されていません"という警告は出ましたが、無事HelloWorldに成功しました！お二方ともご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: ~/.bash_profileに
export JAVA_HOME=`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Comman\
ds/java_home -v "1.6"`
PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
を書き加えたところ警告は出なくなりました。コマンドにオプションをつけるのと比べると、バージョンを切り替えるときは一々このファイルを編集してターミナルを再起動しなければいけないのは面倒ですが・・・